# setTimeout continuous loop without wait

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to get setTimeout to re-run the function it's inside after 15 seconds, it's not waiting 15 seconds and just doing it in a constant loop.

**Here's my current code**

```
function checkSession(x) {
http.abort();
http.open("GET", siteURL+"processes/ajax.php?call=check_session&string="+x+"&new="+Math.random(), true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
        if(http.responseText == true) {
            updateSession(x);
        } else {
            setTimeout(checkSession(x),15000);
        }
    }
}
http.send(null);
}
```

I don't see any problems in the code itself, the only thing wrong is that it's just doing a constant loop without waiting the "15000" miliseconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change the setTimeout call to:

```
setTimeout(function(){checkSession(x)},15000);
```

As you have it now, checkSession is called immediately and then passed as an argument to setTimeout.  Wrapping it inside the function allows for the call to be deferred.

Comment: Correct, but could probably benefit from an explanation as to **why**.

Comment: ..or use `setTimeout(checkSession.bind(null,x), 15000);`

Comment: @jAndy: ...which is not an option in IE 8 and below.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation:

The function is like this: `setTimeout( function, delay );`

Your method call was not setting an anonymous function or reference to a function as the function argument.

Wrong: `setTimeout(checkSession(x),15000);`

Reason: `checkSession(x)` is a function call, not a reference to a function or anonymous function

Right: `setTimeout(function() {checkSession(x) },15000);`

Reason: the function call is now wrapped as an anonymous function in place and the function argument is set for the `setTimeout( function, delay )` method.

Hope that helps to clear it up for you!